# Why does event.getActionMasked switch to these cases when event.getAction doesn't

Tags: java, android, touch, motionevent

when doing `event.getAction()`, if i touched with 3 fingers.  Lets call them finger 0 1 2 in the order they touch, if I remove 2 then 1, `MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP` doesn't get switched to, likewise when i put the fingers down, `MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN` does not get switched to.  But the switch will still go to`MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` when needed to.  But when I change the parameter of the switch to `event.getActionMasked()` then all the cases will be called correctly.  I would like to understand why this is, since in my single touch switch statement, `event.getAction()` works fine.

```
//replace with getAction(), first and third case don't always get called.  Only sometimes.
switch(event.getActionMasked()) 
{
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN: 
        prevZoomX = Math.abs(x1-x2);
        prevZoomY = Math.abs(y1-y2);
        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        float deltaX = (Math.abs(x1-x2) - prevZoomX);
        float deltaY = (Math.abs(y1-y2) - prevZoomY);
        Log.d("zoom","dx: " + deltaX/(mDensity/2) + " prevZoomX " + prevZoomX);
        Log.d("zoom","dy: " + deltaY/(mDensity/2) + " prevZoomY " + prevZoomY);

        mRenderer.zoom = Math.abs(deltaX) > Math.abs(deltaY) ? deltaX/(mDensity/2) : deltaY/(mDensity/2);
        Log.d("zoom","" + mRenderer.zoom);
        prevZoomX = Math.abs(x1-x2);
        prevZoomY = Math.abs(y1-y2);
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
        Log.d("finger","fingers left: " + event.getPointerCount());
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because the getActionMasked()  and getAction() are equals only for the first finger (id = 0).

For example MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN == 5.

For the 1st finger both will be equal 0 (0x0000) so it won't get there,
but for the second  (id = 1) there will be difference getActionMasked() = 5 (0x0005) and getAction() = 261 (0x0105)

So to get in the:

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
```

You should use getActionMasked()!

It filters getAction() result by ACTION_MASK == 255 (0x00FF)

Pointer id will be removed like this:

```
261 & 255 = 5 (0x0105 & 0x00ff = 0x0005)
```

P.S. Pointer will  be extracted with the mask 65280 (0xff00) like:

```
261 & 65280 = 256 (0x0105 & 0xff00 = 0x0100)
```

and then shifted with shift 8:

```
256 >> 8 = 1 (0b100000000 >> 8 = 0b1)
```

Answer (score 0):

From [MotionEvent documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getAction%28%29):

> Consider using getActionMasked() and getActionIndex() to retrieve the separate masked action and pointer index.

I was wondering the same thing, and I assume this sentence means that `getAction()` does not support multiple pointers.